# zxing qrcode quiet

Tags: java, qr-code

i am currently using ZXing-1.6 and i am experiencing problems with this bit of part of the code from QRCodeWriter class

```
private static BitMatrix renderResult(QRCode code, int width, int height) {
ByteMatrix input = code.getMatrix();
int inputWidth = input.getWidth();
int inputHeight = input.getHeight();
int qrWidth = inputWidth + (QUIET_ZONE_SIZE << 1);
int qrHeight = inputHeight + (QUIET_ZONE_SIZE << 1);
int outputWidth = Math.max(width, qrWidth);
int outputHeight = Math.max(height, qrHeight);

int multiple = Math.min(outputWidth / qrWidth, outputHeight / qrHeight);
// Padding includes both the quiet zone and the extra white pixels to accommodate the requested
// dimensions. For example, if input is 25x25 the QR will be 33x33 including the quiet zone.
// If the requested size is 200x160, the multiple will be 4, for a QR of 132x132. These will
// handle all the padding from 100x100 (the actual QR) up to 200x160.
int leftPadding = (outputWidth - (inputWidth * multiple)) / 2;
int topPadding = (outputHeight - (inputHeight * multiple)) / 2;

BitMatrix output = new BitMatrix(outputWidth, outputHeight);

for (int inputY = 0, outputY = topPadding; inputY < inputHeight; inputY++, outputY += multiple) {
  // Write the contents of this row of the barcode
  for (int inputX = 0, outputX = leftPadding; inputX < inputWidth; inputX++, outputX += multiple) {
    if (input.get(inputX, inputY) == 1) {
      output.setRegion(outputX, outputY, multiple, multiple);
    }
  }
}

return output;
```

}

problem is when i get datamatrix size of which is like 60x60 and output matrix should be like 100X100 i get a lot of white space + quiet zone , i guess you are operating with int variables because it's not possible to have a datamarix nod size of like 3.23 and it' should be integer.
Could you help me out and give me some guesses or point me to somewhere , where it is already discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered on the mailing list -- That is a very old version, please use something newer. Yes, there is a minimum margin, and, modules have to be a whole multiple of pixels in size. This can make it smaller than usual. It's normal; otherwise the image would be distorted.